# Define factory class in C++

Tags: c++

I have "like factory" class:

```
class SpecialReader {
private:
    HANDLE specialFile;
    SpecialReader(HANDLE specialFile);
public:
    static SpecialReader Create(TCHAR* fileName);
    ~SpecialReader();
}

//where 

SpecialReader::Create(TCHAR* fileName) {
// ...
// ...

return SpecialReader(inputFile);
}
```

I want to define object in program body like this:

```
SpecialReader myReader;
```

But not:

```
SpecialReader myReader = SpecialReader::Create(anyFile);
```

If I try to define object like in the first case I've got a compiler error:

```
error C2512: 'SpecialReader' : no appropriate default constructor available.
```

How to define this class right?

Comment: Did you try giving it an appropriate default constructor? Although it might be better not to; it's harder to use the class incorrectly if you don't allow default construction.

Comment: I want to disable possibility of creation object without Create method.

Comment: You've already done that. But your question says otherwise: it says you want to be able to default-construct it. You can't both allow and forbid that.

Comment: Ok. Can I leave a memory to create object afterwards?

Comment: @HariSeldon I'm not sure what problem you are really about to solve, but I wrote an answer, that will enable you to _"create object afterwards"_.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I'm trying to avoid exception handling: if Creator() fails it return NULL.

Comment: @HariSeldon You can return an empty `unique_ptr`, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) to do so, the simplest choice is using a [`std::unique_ptr<SpecialReader>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and transfer ownership of the instance to the caller:

```
class SpecialReader {
private:
    HANDLE specialFile;
    SpecialReader(HANDLE specialFile);        
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<SpecialReader> Create(TCHAR* fileName);
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ~SpecialReader();
}

std::unique_ptr<SpecialReader> SpecialReader::Create(TCHAR* fileName) {
    // ...
    return std::unique_ptr<SpecialReader>(new SpecialReader(inputFile));
}
```

---

To get delayed creation you can write as follows. The syntax is slightly different from your OP, but effectively achieves the same:

```
std::unique_ptr<SpecialReader> myReader;

// ....

myReader = SpecialReader::Create(filename);
```

---

As for your comments, that you want to handle failure within the `Create()` factory function, you can return an empty `std::unique_ptr<SpecialReader>`, and let the client check about it:

```
std::unique_ptr<SpecialReader> SpecialReader::Create(TCHAR* fileName) {
    try {
        // ...
        return std::unique_ptr<SpecialReader>(new SpecialReader(inputFile));
    }
    catch(...) {
        // ignore any exceptions
    }
    return std::unique_ptr<SpecialReader>();
}
```

---

```
std::unique_ptr<SpecialReader> myReader;
myReader = SpecialReader::Create(filename);
if(!myReader.get()) {
    // Error handling, Create() couldn't create an instance of SpecialReader
}
```

Comment: friend std::make_unique<SpecialReader>(TCHAR* fileName);  error C2063: 'std::make_unique' not a function

Comment: Did you include the `memory` header and is your compiler capable of c++14 standard features? Instead of using `std::make_unique()` you could also use `return std::unique_ptr<SpecialReader>(new SpecialReader(inputFile));`.

Comment: Yes, I'm include memory header. Second variant work fine (return std::unique_ptr...). But how to delete created object?

Comment: @HariSeldon _"But how to delete created object?"_ Did you already read the [`std::unique_ptr` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)? It's actually purposed to take you out of charge of doing this. The `delete` will be applied as soon the `unique_ptr` instance used goes out of scope, and it owns a object instance. Ownership for the `unique_ptr` is transferred to the calling function on `return`.

Comment: But what if I need to recreate whole reader from scratch in some cases?

Comment: @HSpecialReader _"But what if I need to recreate whole reader from scratch in some cases?"_ You can just acquire another one from `SpecialReader::Create()` and replace your current `myReader`. As mentioned `std::unique_ptr<SpecialReader>` will take care of deleting the old instance, befor achieving the new one. Just read about copy/move constructors and assignment operators in the reference link I have provided in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a do-nothing default constructor?

```
public:
  SpecialReader(){};
```

Comment: If you read the question, you'll recognize the OP doesn't want that (for whatever reasons they have). Only the factory function should be able to create new instances of `SpecialReader`.